# Do I need to create virtual environment through terminal?

Tags: django, pycharm, virtualenv

I am creating a new Django project through PyCharm, I already have Virtualenv selected instead of conda, so do I have to create a virtual environment through the terminal and install all libraries? I am not planning to upload this site on domain or server, it's for my learning, will upload it on Heroku or similar thing to show my practice and work to people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to install it again. Check in your PyCharm settings where the virtual environment has been installed, then all you have to do is:

```
. path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate
```